# Changing the CSS of th, td tags of one table class changes all other tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to adjust the padding on one set of table classes but the changes i'm applying appear on all other tables. Here's my css:

```
.my_table th, td{
   font-size: 14px;
   padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

And here is the related html for that table:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe table my_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>somethingsomething</th>
      <td>somethingsomething</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>somethingsomething</th>
      <td>somethingsomething</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: `, td` essentially means "and select all `td` tags", not "select the td tag within an element with the class of `.my_table`"

Comment: You need to add class name to the 'th' tags that you want to add css  to and in the css : '.my_table classname{.....css code....}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to put .my_table class also to the td element

```css
.my_table th, .my_table td {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the CSS and not make any changes to the html the following might work for you, I've added yellow to the css so it's really obvious what's going on.

```css
table.my_table tr{
font-size: 14px;
padding-bottom: 2em;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2>Table A</h2>
<table border="1" class="dataframe table my_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>somethingsomething</th>
      <td>somethingsomething</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>somethingsomething</th>
      <td>somethingsomething</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 
<h2>Table B</h2>
<table border="1" class="dataframe table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>somethingsomething</th>
      <td>somethingsomething</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>somethingsomething</th>
      <td>somethingsomething</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```